# Phantomjs-prebuilt error

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

> (node:3526) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: PhantomJS binary was not found.
>   This generally means something went wrong when installing
>   phantomjs-prebuilt. Exiting.

This is the error i have.
I tried this : `npm install --force phantomjs-prebuilt` and i got this error.
Link of error: https://hastebin.com/raw/ikosipibum.vbs

I use v6.9.2 of nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you problem is because you don't have tar bz2 support package installed in you OS.

```
bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

Install with `apt-get install bzip2`

Comment: so what command should i use to add tar bz2? i need help becuase i am new at ubuntu.

Comment: I think `apt-get install bzip2` should work, It's been a long time since last time I used Ubuntu

Comment: ok i did it.and after that i uninstalled phantomjs-prebuilt and installed again! it showed me this now : https://hastebin.com/raw/icopazaven.coffeescript

Comment: Sorry I don't have idea about what this '_Unknown system error -122_' means

Comment: Oh this may give a hint:

` npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/cabox/workspace/package.json'
npm WARN workspace No description
npm WARN workspace No repository field.
npm WARN workspace No README data
npm WARN workspace No license field.
`